# keystroke when clicking mouse button

Tags: keyboard, mouse, click

I want to assign the middle mouse button to the `space` key, so I can pan in Photoshop and illustrator without using the keyboard.

I'm sure something like that must exist for Mac OS, but I only find references to the opposite which is making a click with the keyboard.

Comment: Try Bettertouchtool.  have not used it with 3rd party mic, but know there is an option for other mice  Would not be surprised if it can do middle buttons.

Comment: Thanks, in fact I already have BTT installed... but I always thought it was only for the trackpad. D'oh!

Comment: Let us know if it works..  Interested to know and don't have three button mouse lying around

Comment: It worked... but I had to disable Smooth Mouse for it to work. Using Mac OS without smooth mouse is a PITA... so I need another solution for the keystroke.

Answer (score 1):

I found Controller Mate that does exactly what I need, but for some reason it doesn't work in Photoshop or Illustrator. I've tried in other applications and it works...

http://www.orderedbytes.com/controllermate/

The bizarre thing is the hand icon appears, but still no pan, even if I have also set the middle mouse button to perform a left mouse click.